# tensorflow_core module not found

Tags: tensorflow

I am facing this error when trying to use pre-trained models from tensorflow registered on mlflow server. I am running on a docker container on a Linux VM Please see below.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           │          │           │    │        │        └ 0
           │          │           │    │        └ None
           │          │           │    └ 0
           │          │           └ 'tensorflow_core.keras'
           │          └ <function _gcd_import at 0x7f3fd0404430>
           └ <module 'importlib._bootstrap' (frozen)>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core'
```

Here are also the dependencies version being installed:

```
tensorboard                   2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.8.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.2.0
tensorflow-gpu                2.2.0
tensorflow-io                 0.24.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.26.0
```

Really appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. Never post screenshot of textual data this is counter productive and prevent people to help you. Copy paste and format instead that is the proper and smarter way to do it.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help. This is the Error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core'

Comment: Well then edit your post remove the pictures and replace it by texts that is the point of my comment.

Comment: Hi @EAmir, tensorflow_core module is supported in the 2.1 version of the tensorflow and is not supported in the 2.8 version. Thank You.